Issue with Image Upload Function with Strapi v4
I’m currently trying to implement the image upload feature, following this guide:
But here I’ve encountered a problem.

Could someone explain to me how I have to program here?
The default folder ‘public/uploads’ is there, so why does it still ask for ‘tmpWorkingDirectory’?
Is there an example for this?

Strapi Version: 4.21.1
Operating System: Heroku
Database: PostgreSQL
Node Version: 18.20.0
NPM Version: >=6.0.0


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Please share the full error message, we can't see all the lines.
And we will need more information to be able to help.
What is the full function code you have?

You are trying to upload files on Heroku with the default file provider.
It means that you are trying to upload file on the Heroku instance.
This is not possible.
More information here on why: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku
"Heroku has an “ephemeral” hard drive, this means that you can write files to disk"
You will have to setup an AWS3 bucket or use another Upload provider to host your assets.
That's why you have an error.
And the error comes from this function: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/develop/packages/core/upload/server/services/upload.js#L50

Thank you Jim! I think I have now solved the problem. The images should be saved in Cloudinary, I've already done that with Strapi v3. I'll test this via Strapi v4 and report back. I wish you a good start into the new week.

this will work the same - let me know if that works.
Have a great day.
